# Sybase jTDS vs jconnect driver

Tags: sybase

what is difference between jTDS and jconnect drivers of Sybase database. Looks like both of them are Type 4 pure Java drivers. Both use tabular data stream protocol (TDS.. see wikipedia). So how to chose one over other?.